# Recursive template argument removals

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

This seemingly strange question is meant to tackle a general type of recursion that I cannot seem to figure out.  `remove_unit_packs<Pack>::type` shall be `Pack` with all unit packs within it removed, where a unit pack is defined to be any pack of the form `P<T>` (only one element in the pack, though that element can itself be a pack too).  Thus

```
 remove_unit_packs< std::tuple<int, P<float>, char> >::type
```

shall be

```
 std::tuple<int, char>
```

Here is my implementation for this, which uses recursion:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
struct is_unit_pack : std::false_type { };

template <template <typename> class P, typename T>
struct is_unit_pack<P<T>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T, typename Output = std::tuple<>>
struct remove_unit_packs { using type = T; };

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Output>
struct remove_unit_packs<P<>, std::tuple<Output...>> {
    using type = P<Output...>;
};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output>
struct remove_unit_packs<P<First, Rest...>, std::tuple<Output...>> : std::conditional_t<is_unit_pack<First>::value,
    remove_unit_packs<P<Rest...>, std::tuple<Output...>>,
    remove_unit_packs<P<Rest...>, std::tuple<Output..., typename remove_unit_packs<First>::type>>  // We use 'typename remove_unit_packs<First>::type>' instead of simply 'First' in case 'First' contains a unit pack despite not being a unit pack (in which case all unit packs must be removed from within 'First').
> { };

// Test
template <typename...> struct P;

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs< std::tuple<int, P<float>, char> >::type,
        std::tuple<int, char>
    >::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs< std::tuple<int, P<float, P<P<P<void>>, bool, int>, long>, char> >::type,
        std::tuple<int, P<float, P<bool, int>, long>, char>
    >::value);
}
```

Note as another example, however, that

```
 remove_unit_packs< std::tuple<int, P<float, P<bool>>, char> >::type
```

is

```
 std::tuple<int, P<float>, char>
```

But this output type also contains a single pack (`P<float>`), which I would like to be removed as well, i.e. keep removing all unit packs until there are no unit packs anywhere at all (except in the special case that the original pack has become a unit pack, in which case keep that as is).  But my code above doesn't do this, because it carries out only one pass of removals.  I could call two passes to get the job done, but then there will be cases that will require 3, or who knows how many passes, to remove all unit packs completely.  But I'm stuck figuring out how to do this.  Can anyone shed some ideas here, which hopefully addresses how this type of thing is done in general?

**Update:**

I think I have an idea:

Change my

```
template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Output>
struct remove_unit_packs<P<>, std::tuple<Output...>> {
    using type = P<Output...>;
};
```

from above to

```
template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Output>
struct remove_unit_packs<P<>, std::tuple<Output...>> {
    using result = P<Output...>;
    using type = std::conditional_t<contains_unit_pack<result>::value,
        typename remove_unit_packs<result>::type,   
        result
    >;
};
```

where `template <typename Pack> struct contains_unit_pack` I will define.  My compiler currently complains of circular logic or something though.  If anyone thinks this won't work, or that there might be a better way altogether, please let me know.

Comment: @ max66   No, `remove_unit_packs< std::tuple<int, P<float, P<bool>>, char> >::type` shall have `P<bool>` removed, which gives us `std::tuple<int, P<float>, char>`, but that itself has a unit pack, so in turn it should become `std::tuple<int, char>`.

Comment: sorry: I've misunderstood  your words; reading they a second (well... a fourth) time, I've understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want but seems to me that you have to make recursive `is_unit_pack`.

Something like

```
template <typename T>
struct is_unit_pack : std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct is_unit_pack<C<Ts...>>
   : std::integral_constant<bool,
        (2 > sumI<(false == is_unit_pack<Ts>{})...>::value)>
 { };
```

where `sumI` is a sum of variadic integers

```
template <int ...>
struct sumI
 { static constexpr int value { 0 }; };

template <int I, int ... Is>
struct sumI<I, Is...>
 { static constexpr int value { I + sumI<Is...>::value }; };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>


template <typename...>
struct P
 { };

template <int ...>
struct sumI
 { static constexpr int value { 0 }; };

template <int I, int ... Is>
struct sumI<I, Is...>
 { static constexpr int value { I + sumI<Is...>::value }; };

template <typename T>
struct is_unit_pack : std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct is_unit_pack<C<Ts...>>
   : std::integral_constant<bool,
        (2 > sumI<(false == is_unit_pack<Ts>{})...>::value)>
 { };

template <typename T, typename Output = std::tuple<>>
struct rupH
 { using type = T; };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename First, typename... Rest,
          typename... Output>
struct rupH<C<First, Rest...>, std::tuple<Output...>>
   : rupH<C<Rest...>, typename std::conditional<is_unit_pack<First>{},
        std::tuple<Output...>,
        std::tuple<Output..., typename rupH<First>::type>>::type>
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Output>
struct rupH<C<>, std::tuple<Output...>>
 { using type = C<Output...>; };

template <typename T>
using rupH_t = typename rupH<T>::type;

template <typename T>
struct remove_unit_packs
 { using type = T; };

template <template <typename ...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct remove_unit_packs<C<Ts...>>
 { using type = rupH_t<C<Ts...>>; };

template <typename T>
using remove_unit_packs_t = typename remove_unit_packs<T>::type;

int main ()
 {
   static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int, long>>,
        std::tuple<int, long>>{}, "!");

   static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int>>,
        std::tuple<int>>{}, "!");

   static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int, P<long>, long>>,
        std::tuple<int, long>>{}, "!");

   static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int, P<P<long>>, long>>,
        std::tuple<int, long>>{}, "!");

   static_assert(std::is_same<
      remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int, P<float, P<bool>>, char>>,
      std::tuple<int, char>>{}, "!");

   static_assert(std::is_same<
      remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int, P<float, P<char>, bool>, char>>,
      std::tuple<int, P<float, bool>, char>>{}, "!");
 }
```

If you can use C++17, `sumI` isn't necessary and you can use fold expression; `is_unit_pack` become simply

```
template <typename T>
struct is_unit_pack : std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct is_unit_pack<C<Ts...>>
   : std::integral_constant<bool,
        (2 > ((false == is_unit_pack<Ts>{}) + ...))>
 { };
```

Comment: It seems to give everything I stated, so I think you understood my specs correctly.  Thanks a lot.  It won't compile if `P<>` is placed anywhere within the pack though, but I'm sure one more specialization would fix that.  I'm still working on my solution using a different method, and will post it if successful.  I will also try to generalize to n-packs (packs of length n being removed completely).

Comment: Good solution to use depth recursion in the `is_unit_pack` trait.

Answer (score 1):

In C++17 it is simple to get rid of the "breadth recursion". As a result, there is only "depth recursion". Based on the `is_unit_type` trait from [max66's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46985839/2615118):

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<class...> struct P {};

// same as in [max66's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46985839/2615118)
template <typename T>
struct is_unit_pack : std::false_type
{ };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct is_unit_pack<C<Ts...>>
  : std::integral_constant<bool,
               (2 > ((false == is_unit_pack<Ts>{}) + ...))>
{ };

template<template<class> class Pred, class... Ts>
constexpr size_t count_if() {
  return (size_t(0) + ... + Pred<Ts>{});
}

template<template<class> class Pred, class... Ts>
constexpr auto which() {
  constexpr auto flags = std::array{bool(Pred<Ts>{})...};
  constexpr size_t osize = count_if<Pred, Ts...>();
  auto inds = std::array<size_t, osize>{};
  auto it = inds.begin();
  for(size_t i=0; i<flags.size(); ++i) if(flags[i]) *it++ = i;
  return inds;
}

template<template<class> class Pred, class Ts, class Is>
struct keep_rec_if_impl;

template<template<class> class Pred, class T>
struct keep_rec_if {// non-specialized version for non-packs
  using R = T;// break the depth recursion (see below)
};

template<template<class> class Pred, class... Ts>
struct keep_rec_if<Pred, P<Ts...>> {// specialized version for packs
  static constexpr size_t osize = count_if<Pred, Ts...>();
  using IndSeq = std::make_index_sequence<osize>;
  using R = typename keep_rec_if_impl<Pred, P<Ts...>, IndSeq>::R;
};

template<template<class> class Pred, class... Ts>
using keep_rec_if_t = typename keep_rec_if<Pred, Ts...>::R;

template<template<class> class Pred, class... Ts, size_t... is>
struct keep_rec_if_impl<Pred, P<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<is...>> {
  static constexpr auto inds = which<Pred, Ts...>();
  template<size_t i> using T = std::tuple_element_t<inds[i], std::tuple<Ts...>>;
  using R = P<keep_rec_if_t<Pred, T<is>>...>;// depth-recursion only
};

template<template<class> class Pred, class Ts>
struct remove_rec_if {
  template<class U>
  using NotPred = std::integral_constant<bool, !Pred<U>{}>;
  using R = keep_rec_if_t<NotPred, Ts>;
};

template<template<class> class Pred, class Ts>
using remove_rec_if_t = typename remove_rec_if<Pred, Ts>::R;

template<class Ts>
using remove_unit_packs_t = remove_rec_if_t<is_unit_pack, Ts>;

int main () {
  static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<P<int, long>>,
        P<int, long>>{}, "!");

  static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<P<int>>,
        P<int>>{}, "!");

  static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<P<int, P<long>, long>>,
        P<int, long>>{}, "!");

  static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<P<int, P<P<long>>, long>>,
        P<int, long>>{}, "!");

  static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<P<int, P<float, P<bool>>, char>>,
        P<int, char>>{}, "!");

  static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<P<int, P<float, P<char>, bool>, char>>,
        P<int, P<float, bool>, char>>{}, "!");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: By using another style for the "indices trick" one can also [get rid of `keep_rec_if_impl`](https://godbolt.org/g/fZh1DZ).

Answer (score 0):

My method worked, but I'll have to accept max66's more original solution.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail {
    template <bool...> struct any_of;

    template <>
    struct any_of<> : std::false_type {};

    template <bool... Bs>
    struct any_of<true, Bs...> : std::true_type {};

    template <bool First, bool... Rest>
    struct any_of<First, Rest...> : any_of<Rest...> {};
}

template <typename T>
struct is_unit_pack : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename> class P, typename T>
struct is_unit_pack<P<T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T> struct contains_unit_pack : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
struct contains_unit_pack<P<Ts...>> : 
    detail::any_of<(is_unit_pack<Ts>::value || contains_unit_pack<Ts>::value)...> {};

// remove_unit_packs
template <typename T, typename Output = std::tuple<>>
struct remove_unit_packs {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename Result, bool>
struct check {
    using type = Result;    
};

template <typename Result>
struct check<Result, true> : remove_unit_packs<Result> {};  // The key recursive call.

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Output>
struct remove_unit_packs<P<>, std::tuple<Output...>> :
    check<P<Output...>, contains_unit_pack<P<Output...>>::value> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output>
struct remove_unit_packs<P<First, Rest...>, std::tuple<Output...>> : std::conditional_t<is_unit_pack<First>::value,
    remove_unit_packs<P<Rest...>, std::tuple<Output...>>,
    remove_unit_packs<P<Rest...>, std::tuple<Output..., typename remove_unit_packs<First>::type>>  // We use 'typename remove_unit_packs<First>::type>' instead of simply 'First' in case 'First' contains a unit pack despite not being a unit pack (in which case all unit packs must be removed from within 'First').
> {};

template <typename T>
using remove_unit_packs_t = typename remove_unit_packs<T>::type;

// Test
template <typename...> struct P;

int main() {
   static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int, P<>>>,
        std::tuple<int, P<>>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int>>,
        std::tuple<int>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int, P<long>, long>>,
        std::tuple<int, long>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<
        remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int, P<P<long>>, long>>,
        std::tuple<int, long>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<
      remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int, P<float, P<bool>>, char>>,
      std::tuple<int, char>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<
      remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int, P<float, P<char>, bool>, char>>,
      std::tuple<int, P<float, bool>, char>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<
      remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int, P<float, P<char>, bool>, char>>,
      std::tuple<int, P<float, bool>, char>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<
      remove_unit_packs_t<std::tuple<int, P<P<float, P<bool>, P<long>>, int, P<void>>, P<P<char, bool>>>>,
      std::tuple<int>>{});
}
```